# Multiple TCP socket connections Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-multithreading

I'm new to socket programming and I'm struggling to connect to and exchange information using multiple TCP sockets.

I have a setup with two development boards written in C and a PC with a Python script. The two boards and PC are connected to a switch with LAN-cables. Both development boards are programmed to send back "OK" as soon as they receive data from the PC.

I want to connect to both of the boards and keep sockets open while I send and receive info with my Python script. If I connect to only *one* board I can do that without any problems. But if I try to connect to two boards, the connection times out either during establishing the connection or during communication.

Here is my code:

**main.py**

```
from board import Board

b1 = Board(1, "192.168.0.254", 5)
b2 = Board(2, "192.168.0.77", 7)

b1.establish_connection()
b2.establish_connection()

while True:
    pass
```

**board.py**

```
import threading
import socket
import random
import time
import select

class Board():
    def __init__(self, nr, host_address, port_nr):
        self.server_addr = (host_address, port_nr)
        self.nr = nr
        self.dt = 10


    def establish_connection(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.settimeout(5)
        print("Trying to establish a connection board {}".format(self.nr), self.server_addr)
        try:
            self.s.connect(self.server_addr)
            threading.Thread(target = self.communication).start()
            print("Connection established board {}".format(self.nr))
            return True
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Not connected. Connetion timeout.")
            return False
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Not connected. " + str(e) + ".")
            return False


    def communication(self):
        while True:
            self.send_data([random.randint(0,500), random.randint(0,500), random.randint(0,500)])
            start_time = time.time()
            while (start_time + self.dt) >= time.time():
                data = self.receive_data()
                if data is not None:
                    print(data)
                    break

    def send_data(self, a):
        x, y, z = a[0], a[1], a[2]
        msg = "S,X%i,Y%i,Z%i,E" %(x,y,z)
        print("Sending msg {0}".format(msg))
        nsent = self.s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

    def receive_data(self):
        readable_s, _, _ = select.select([self.s], [], [], 0.001)
        if readable_s:
            msg = self.s.recv(20).decode('utf-8')
            return msg
```

I also have the same problem when I use Hercules instead of the python script. In the picture you can see that it was able to connect to both of the development boards, but didn't send "OK" back after receiving data. [image: picture]

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add: `time.sleep(20); print('All Done')` to the end of your main.py?

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference if I add `time.sleep(20); print('All Done')` or any other code that would prolong the run time of main.py.

Comment: Do you need to use `select`? Can you do: `def receive_data(self): return self.s.recv()`?

Comment: I need to use `select`, because I need the `recive_data(self)` function to be non-blocking. However both with and without `select` the result is the same: the PC connects to one board and the connection for the other board goes to timeout.

Comment: Have you got two PCs, one to connect to `192.168.0.254` and the other to `192.168.0.77`, but on the same LAN? Each PC should be able to connect to one board as you have demonstrated already.

Comment: It's my number one priority that I can control the both of the boards from one PC. In my application I need to control more than two boards, but as the problem already arose with two, I worded the problem in a such way.

Comment: I'm just trying to eliminate some variables. You say that one PC communicating with one dev board works OK. Lets build on that and have two PCs each communicating with a different dev board, but on the same network.

Comment: @quamrana Sorry, I misread your comment earlier. I tried connecting one PC to `192.168.0.254` and one to `192.168.0.77`, but on the same LAN and it didn't work. So it seems like it's a network problem. I have also tried to connect through the WIFI and have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, network problems was on my list. I hope you can sort that out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was not in the python code, but the fact that the boards had a gateway specified. Simultaneous communication started working once the gateway was changed back to 0.0.0.0 in the C code uploaded on the development boards. In addition each board had to have different MAC address.